# How to use partition to run a subquery by calling a function in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How can I use `partition` run a subquery by calling a function with the value as parameter?

```
range day from 1 to 50 step 1
| partition by day
{
   function_call(day)  
}
```

that doesn't work, but if I do feed a constant

```
range day from 1 to 50 step 1
| partition by day
{
   function_call(10)  
}
```

then it will work, but it becomes a union of the function call with the same parameter, not really what I want though....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please have a look at [user-defined functions usage restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#user-defined-functions-usage-restrictions), specifically #1-2 (assuming I guessed correctly what your function, `function_call()`, does):

> 1. User-defined functions can't pass into `toscalar()` invocation information that depends on the row-context in which the function is called.
> 2. User-defined functions that return a tabular expression can't be invoked with an argument that varies with the row context.
> 3. A function taking at least one tabular input can't be invoked on a remote cluster.
> 4. A scalar function can't be invoked on a remote cluster.

Depending on what your function, `function_call()` does, you could achieve your goal in a different way. But you'll need to specify the logic of that function if you need further assistance.

Comment: I see, what I really want just to call a function N time, with a pattern of the parameters that I can easily generate by using `range`. I see many people are requesting this kind of query, and I was not optimistic I could do it. Is there any roadmap Kusto query might consider supporting this?

Comment: > *"Depending on what your function, `function_call()` does, you could achieve your goal in a different way. But you'll need to specify the logic of that function if you need further assistance."* perhaps, you could give an example. Regardless, feature requests are tracked @ https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice